# C++ cout will not print

Tags: c++, printing, program-entry-point, cout

What the title says, cout will not print anything! But main finished normally and returns a negative number, what's going on? Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
unsigned long fibonacci(long unsigned int *);
int main(void)
{
    cout<<"IT WILL NOT PRINT!!!!!";
    unsigned long int fib[4000000];
    cout<<"SUM OF EVEN FIBONACCI NUMBERS: "<<fibonacci(fib)<<endl;
    return 0;
}
unsigned long fibonacci(unsigned long int *FIBO)
{
    unsigned long i;
    int sum=0,c=0, *EVEN = new int[2000000];
    FIBO[0]=1; FIBO[1]=2;
    for (i=2;i<3999999;i++){
        FIBO[i]=FIBO[i-1]+FIBO[i-2];
        if (FIBO[i]%2==0){
            EVEN[c]=FIBO[i];
            sum+=EVEN[c];
            c++;
        }
    }
    delete [] EVEN;
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please post your code into your question. Indent with four spaces to make it look like code on the site. Good luck!

Comment: try putting an `endl` after your *first* `cout`.  You're probably failing in `fibonacci` just before you flush stdout.

Comment: @PaulEvans I did but that's not the problem, as you can see it doesn't print the cout<<"IT WILL NOT PRINT!!!!!"; which is right after the main :(

Comment: Believe it is not the same I have tried this post and nothing.
Actually nothing works! I even return 293; after int main(void) and nothing, why is that?

Comment: It's not the same because your program is crashing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::cout` by default is buffered.  Without an explicit flush, you won't see anything printed until the internal buffers need to be flushed.  This is done for performance reasons.

You can add a specific flush, like so:
`std::cout<<"IT WILL NOT PRINT!!!!!" << std::endl;`

That said, you're not seeing output because ***your program is crashing***.

`unsigned long int fib[4000000];` is going to require nearly 15MB of space (on a 32bit long int platform).  There simply won't be enough stack space to allocate such a large block of memory within that storage duration.

For such large blocks you will need to dynamically allocate the block, or better yet:

`std::vector<unsigned long int> fib(4000000);`

Comment: still the same problem ;(

Comment: So, this doesn't print anything?  `#include <iostream> int main { std::cout << "Hello." }`?  If it _does_, your real program is crashing (and no, you won't see the output).

Comment: @SasukeItachiUchihaClan: Your program crashes for me too, but if I decrease the size of the huge array "fib", it doesn't crash.

Comment: that does print, but even after using flush and endl on my program it won't do anything, actually it is not a cout problem, it won't do anythinhg, just returns a negative number. I even return -293 after int main(void){ but nothing happens

Comment: Because your program is crashing.  Did you not read the answer?  You can't allocate 15MB on the stack, it will crash immediately -- before it does anything else.

Comment: @ThomasPadron-McCarthy so it's the size , because probably c++ can't support 4 million integers on an array? That's the logical explanation

Comment: Not 4 million integers _on the stack_. You need to allocate it differently.

Comment: @Chad I read the answer but it doesn't crash, it returns a negative number

Comment: The code you wrote doesn't return anything but 0.  So, if you are seeing anything else (return of a negative number) that _is_ a crash.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: My suggestion is in my answer.  If you need `fib`, use a `std::vector` to hold it.

Comment: There are other errors now, but anyway at least I found the answer, I need to learn vectors. I guess this problem should be solved now.

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a look at this problem: we want to produce a sum of even Fibonacci numbers within a predefined range.

Rearranged with minor edits for clarity:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
unsigned long fibonacci(unsigned long int *FIBO)
{
    unsigned long i;
    int sum=0,c=0, *EVEN = new int[2000000];
    FIBO[0]=1; FIBO[1]=2;
    for (i=2;i<3999999;i++){
        FIBO[i]=FIBO[i-1]+FIBO[i-2];
        if (FIBO[i]%2==0){
            EVEN[c]=FIBO[i];
            sum+=EVEN[c];
            c++;
        }
    }
    delete [] EVEN;
    return sum;
}
int main(void)
{
    unsigned long int fib[4000000];
    cout << "SUM OF EVEN FIBONACCI NUMBERS: " << fibonacci(fib) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

First, let's remove unneeded code in the function fibonacci. We don't need to store even numbers, so we'll remove the EVEN array.

```
unsigned long fibonacci(unsigned long *FIBO)
{
    unsigned long i, sum=0;
    FIBO[0]=1; FIBO[1]=2;
    for (i=2;i<3999999;i++){
        FIBO[i]=FIBO[i-1]+FIBO[i-2];
        if (FIBO[i]%2==0){
            sum += FIBO[i];
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

We can get a bit more clever though- we can prove that every third Fibonacci number will be even. Starting from Fib(0)=0, this allows us to make a new function:

```
unsigned long sum_even_fibonacci(unsigned long n)
{
    unsigned long i, a=0, b=1, c=1, sum=0;
    for (i=0;i<n/3;i++){
        a = b + c; // Fib(3i)
        b = a + c; // Fib(3i+1)
        c = a + b; // Fib(3i+2)
        sum += a;  // Fib(3i) will always be even- add it to sum.
    }
    return sum;
}
```

This should produce the sum of the even Fibonacci numbers within the first n numbers of the series.

The new program, in full:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
unsigned long sum_even_fibonacci(unsigned long n)
{
    unsigned long i, a=0, b=1, c=1, sum=0;
    for (i=0;i<n/3;i++){
        a = b + c; // Fib(3i)
        b = a + c; // Fib(3i+1)
        c = a + b; // Fib(3i+2)
        sum += a;  // Fib(3i) will always be even- add it to sum.
    }
    return sum;
}
int main(void)
{
    cout << "SUM OF EVEN FIBONACCI NUMBERS: " << sum_even_fibonacci(4000000) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> But main finished normally and returns a negative number,

In your code `main` returns `0` and that is the only return path. So, the process exiting with a negative return code means that `main()` never finished.

Most likely, the array `unsigned long int fib[4000000];` is too large for your system's default stack size, and the operating system handles this by making your process exit with that negative number.

To fix this, either make that array a *lot* smaller or remove it entirely; or use dynamic allocation.

Note that there is no need to even have this array (and no need for `EVEN` either). You're keeping the sum as you go, so you only need to keep the last 2 numbers ; not the entire history.